# Facebook Oauth not picking user_birthday permission

Tags: facebook, oauth

I am passing the following scopes to [this Facebook OAuth URL](https://facebook.com/dialog/oauth)

`scope=email,user_birthday,user_relationships`

But the permission screen that I am having is not showing the `birthday permission`

See Attached Pic[image]

And hence I am not getting the birthday field as well.

Please suggest what has changed.
The [permission doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions) still has `user_birthday` in scope

[This URL](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=769655866548600&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcrm2.floweraura.com%2Fs7check%2Ffboauth%2Fconnect&display=popup&scope=email%2Cuser_birthday%2Cuser_relationships) can be clicked to see the exact Issue.

Comment: You are not actually passing `Cuser_birthday`, right? Please show the actual code you are using. // If you are testing this with an account that does not have a role in the app, then of course you need to get your app’s use of that permission before.

Comment: Cuser_birthday was a typo I have corrected that in the question now,Thanks. [ If you are testing this with an account that does not have a role in the app, then of course you need to get your app’s use of that permission before ] The first step in Oauth is what I am asking for. When I am using the abouve URL the permission screen that I am having is not showing the user_birthday permission shown on pop-up

Comment: Also, I have added the URL in question itself. This will show you the exact screen that I have reported.

Comment: You need to get your app reviewed, before you can ask users that do not have a role in the app for the permission.